# problem in accessing dojoAttachpoints

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a js map which has dojoAttachpoints as keys .Now am iterating the map  as follows

//errorMap holds dojoAttachpoints as keys 
for(var key in this.errorLableMap){
     this.key.className = "ibm-error";
}

Am getting error saying this.key is undefined

Comment: I am going to try not to answer any more of your question, until you read up on JavaScript (it is *not* Java, and completely different) and Dojo.

Answer (score 0):

You **really** should read up on your JavaScript.  This is very elementary:

```
for(var key in this.errorLableMap){ key.className = "ibm-error"; }
```

`this.key` refers to the "key" property under the "this" object.  `key` refers to the variable called "key".  They are completely different things in JavaScript.

This is not Java.

Comment: You are both wrong. Javascript "for-in" loop does not iterate the values of a map. It iterates over keys. So "key" in his example is actually the string for the map. this.errorLabelMap[key].className is what you're looking for.